# BigInt calculation with nodejs

Tags: node.js, bigint, calc

i try to get 3 ranges between 2 bigint values in nodejs. My current code looks like:

```
  var start = -9223372036854775807;
  var end = 9223372036854775807;
  var steps = (end - start) / 3;
  console.log(start);
  for (let xx = 0; xx < 3; xx++) {
    end = start + steps;
    console.log(`${start} - ${end}`);
    start = start + steps;
  }
```

but this is already incorrect, the output looks like:

```
-9223372036854776000
-9223372036854776000 - -3074457345618259000
-3074457345618259000 - 3074457345618258000
3074457345618258000 - 9223372036854775000
```

the final result should be 3 steps in a range of -9223372036854775807 and 9223372036854775807

any hints why node is cutting the last digest ?

Comment: Well, don't BigInt constants have an `n` at the end, like `var start = -9223372036854775807n;`? Or is that not true for nodejs?

Comment: By the way, I'm probably missing something, bit it seems your start value is a negative, so subtracting that from the end would give you a bigger number; are you sure this is what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare all your numbers as BigInt values with the `n` suffix including the `3n`.  Without that suffix, these are just being treated as regular values (no BigInt values) and you're overflowing what they can contain.

```js
let start = -9223372036854775807n;
let end = 9223372036854775807n;
let steps = (end - start) / 3n;
console.log(`before loop: start = ${start}, steps = ${steps}`);
for (let xx = 0; xx < 3; xx++) {
    end = start + steps;
    console.log(`in loop: start = ${start}, end = ${end}`);
    start = start + steps;
}
```

Please note that because your `start` value is negative and you're calculating steps as `(end - start) / 3n`, you're going to get a very large number for the steps.  I'm not entirely sure this is really what you intended, but this code will do the proper BigInt math on the numbers you specified.